# Why isn't RAM as fast as registers/cache memory?

Tags: caching, memory, hardware, ram

Why do we need to cache in Cache Memory? Why cant RAM Memory be made as fast as register or Cache Memory or Cache be as large as RAM Memory (4GB) so that everything can be in cache? Any good article/books to understand these concepts?

Comment: +1 for a question that I've always just "blindly assumed was the case" but never took the time to really ask myself why...

Comment: The "code" book by Petzold may touch on this, it is also very elementary.  You are jumping across decades of technology in your question.  There are microcontrollers, like old processors, where ram and registers are the same speed.  Mostly the answer is "by design", "for cost".  You could make a processor with 4GB of ram, no wait state, but nobody would buy it due to the price.

Comment: there are often multiple layers of cache, the most expensive and fastest memory is at the lowest layer of cache, and the size is driven by chip real estate and in particular price, how many people would pay $4000 for the processor in their computer only to get a little more l1 cache?  Not many, not enough.  The closer to the processor (cache) memory is wants to be closer to the processor speed, processor in the gigahertz would want memory whose round trip time for a read is at similar speeds.

Comment: 1333MHz dram is not 1333MHz memory read cycle timing, the mhz comes from the bus speed to the chip, where multiple transactions are in flight, the round trip though is incredibly slow.  system engineering, x86 in particular, relies so heavily on layers of caching, if you were to turn off those caches your computer would be painfully slow.  Thats the beauty of it though, a little expensive memory, a little more not as expensive memory that is half or a quarter the speed and a lot of slow memory.

Comment: memory takes from one to four transistors per bit depending on the technology, to make them practical to manufacture, get a reasonable yield, etc your die size has limits, they need to be very dense but still take up a lot of chip real estate.  When you start to clock this faster and faster, the price goes up and the power consumption goes up, yield goes down.  Memories with die sizes similar to the processor running at processor speeds would be processor priced.  The processor only runs those speeds inside the chip, the I/O around the chip is much much slower, and chip to chip would be/is

Comment: slow, so even if you had a few hundred dollar, many megabit to gigabit memory chip that could handle gigahertz round trip transactions it would be a waste as your I/O is not that fast.  You would need it on the same chip as the processor, running into die size problems on top of everything else.

Comment: this is why microcontrollers can still do this all on one chip, count up the number of transistors you need, balance the prossing needs to memory needs to go with it, add flash on the same package, leaving only gpio around the edges.  there is no demand for gigahertz microcontrollers but they could make them.  instead the demand is to have all of this for about a buck per controller.  different market.

Comment: for the one transistor per bit memories (dram) you are relying on the capacitance of that transistor to store the data.  Think of it as not a transistor but a wee bitty rechargeable battery that loses its charge in less than a second.  You have to have logic and clock cycles where you are recharging that battery.  In order to get those densities, two to four times more bits per package than other technologies/tricks, you sacrifice clock cycles to start because of all the refresh cycles.  To make the refresh cycles more efficient you make the memories wider.

Comment: 64 bit only for example, you want to read a byte you read 64 bits and extract the 8 you were interested in.  you want to write a byte you read 64, change one byte, and write 64 back, here again costing you performance in order to get density.  As I started, you are crossing decades of technology with your question, a yo-yo or see-saw of back and forth, improve density/size/capacity of the memory, then try to recover some performance, increase the size, try to cover performance.  layers of caches are both smart and a lazy solution allowing the performance to suffer for size...

Comment: obviously this question should not have been closed...use google to research sram vs dram.  DDR dram for example is what we use today, using ddr in the search may uncover even more about how it works.  You have to infer where the performance hits and cost are while reading about the technology.  Then if you want look up caching to understand how caches smooth things out, and infer that cache memory is made up of expensive sram, and is generally much much faster memory than the dram or other caches behind it.

Answer (score 10):

Faster stuff costs more per bit. So you have a descending chain of storage, from a few registers at one end, through several levels of cache, down to RAM. Each level is bigger and slower than the one before. And all the way at the bottom you have disk.

Comment: True, you could have all your memory be TLB memory, but the cost would be astronomical.

Comment: What exactly is adding cost to the manufacturing of cache astronomically more compared to RAM ?

Comment: Short answer is, different kinds of electronic circuitry. Here's one article that explains some of it: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-sram-and-dram/

Comment: This.  L1/2/3 Cache is made out of SRAM.  Main memory is DRAM.  SRAM is faster, but requires more transistors per bit, which makes it more expensive, more power hungry, and requires more chips (won't fit on a typical DIMM).If you can ever find an old 386/486 mobo with off-chip L2 cache, look at the SRAM chips, and you'll see what I mean.  In the old days, a lot of laptops omitted L2 cache for this reason.

Answer (score 7):

Registers and cache are on the cpu chip itself, or tied to it very closely.  Normal RAM is accessed through an address bus, and it often subject to a level of indirection by memory mapping.

Comment: Why cant we put the whole RAM or make cache as large as RAM in the CPU chip itself ? or why the limitation on the size of registers or cache to sizes far lesser than RAM ?

Comment: Because you can only put so many circuits on a chip before the size gets too big, and the yield goes down, the cost goes up, and the power requirements go up.

Comment: Speed of the bus in only a partial answer, most of the perf limits of the memory bus are a result of SRAM vs DRAM (see Tom Zych's answer).

Comment: Does anybody remember when some other company came out with a 386 before IBM did, they used SRAM because they didn't think DRAM was fast enough?